# OAuth -Authorization Server deployment location (DMZ or intranet)

Tags: api, rest, security, oauth-2.0

Developing OAuth Framework for client credential flow to secure communication between services.
Plan is to leverage this OAuth framework to secure API calls originating from the DMZ (public facing APIs) to internal APIs or to the Apis deployed in the DMZ.

This Authorization server has a backend database. Where should be the Authorization Server (which issues Access tokens) to be deployed.

Is this appropriate to deploy in DMZ or intranet?

if Authorization Server deployed in DMZ, do the backend database has to be deployed in DMZ, which is not a good practice.

if Authorization Server deployed in intranet, how to establish trust/authentication between the DMZ Apis to Authorization server (API) - is it solely based on IP address.

what is the good practice/recommendation

Suggest Good Practices/industry standard

Comment: Anything that doesn't need to be exposed to the public internet should be in the place with the least access. If the internet doesn't need access to your OAuth2 server, don't expose it to the internet.